# How do we dispatch to different class methods based on the number of input arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, dispatch, overload-resolution

We want to have a class with two methods of the same name, however:

> 1. there exists a method which accepts exactly one argument.
> 2. The other method accepts two or more arguments.

Maybe, to implement multi-dispatching a person can download a third party library.

Maybe, another option is to decorate the function with a decorator which ***curries*** the function.

Maybe, we then use `functools.singledispatch` to decorate the curried function?

```python
class K:
    @dispatch
    def method():
        pass

    @method.register
    def method_of_one(one_arg):
        return the_slowball_klass

    # method.register(method_of_one)  

    @method.register
    def method_of_two(one_arg, two_args):
        return the_slowball_klass

    # method_of_two = method.register(method_of_two)
```

Comment: These should simply be two separate methods. If you know how many arguments you have, you almost certainly know which method to call.

Comment: `functools.singledispatch` requires type annotations for the first argument, and requires overloads to differ by type.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `*args` as the input type to make it accept a variable number of args then switch on arg length. Or if your goal is just accepting multiple args then that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you a basic approach that doesn't handle edge-cases, but it should get you going

```
import inspect
import types

class dispatch:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.funcs = {}
        self.register(func)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func = self.funcs[len(args) + len(kwargs)]
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    def register(self, func):
        self.funcs[len(inspect.signature(func).parameters)] = func
        return self
    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return types.MethodType(self, obj)

class K:
    @dispatch
    def foo(self):
        return 0
    @foo.register
    def foo(self, a):
        return a
    @foo.register
    def foo(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

In the REPL:

```
In [2]: k = K()

In [3]: k.foo()
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: k.foo(1)
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: k.foo(1, 2)
Out[5]: 3
```